# Problems with android CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I am using a standard android code to listen for network connectivity changes.

But in my Moto G (Lollipop), Whenever I switch from one network to another, I am not getting an event for Network disconnection.

If I switch from NetworkA to NetworkB. I am getting a CONNECTED event for NetworkB but not getting a disconnected event for NetworkA.

This happens on some Samsung devices(MarshMallow) also

Whether there is an reliable way to get notified for network connectivity changes ?

**Registering CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE Receiver**

```
<receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**MyReciver Code**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        LOG.i(" Received connectivity change event. ");
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            String networkType = intent.getParcelableExtra(
            ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_TYPE);
            final NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(
            ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
            final NetworkInfo networkInfo =   connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            final String reason = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            final String connectivityAction = intent.getParcelableExtra(
            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            LOG.i(String.format("+++++ action = %s, networkType = %s, otherNetworkInfo = %s, "
            + "reason = %s,  connectAction = %s, ActiveNetworkInfo = %s", action, networkType,
            otherNetworkInfo, reason, connectivityAction, networkInfo));
    }
}
```

Comment: and the problem is...?

Comment: I am looking for an approach to get connectivity changes notification reliably